# Check if a line and a mesh intersect in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, line, intersection, mesh

I have some cilinders in the scene. When user clicks on some specific points, I´m drawing a line (THREE.Line) between the points. I need to check if the line intersects with any of the cilinders (THREE.Mesh).

this is not working

```
myLine.intersectObjects( arrayOfCilinders , true)
```

is it possible to draw a ray over the line? In that case I could use

```
myRay.intersectObjects( arrayOfCilinders , true)
```

Thanks!

Comment: check raycaster or ray in three.js docs

Comment: That is what i wanted to do, but i dont know how to simulate a ray over the line that i already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Three.js documentation:

> Ray(origin, direction)
>
> origin -- Vector3 The origin of the Ray.
>
> direction -- Vector3 The direction of the Ray.

So if you have *pointA* and *pointB* that are the clicks of the user, you can:

(pseudo code)

```
origin = pointA
direction = (pointB-pointA).normalize()
myRay = THREE.Ray(origin, direction)
```

You can do the same with a `THREE.Raycaster()`